# interpreting R native boxplot function

Tags: r

I'm very new to R. I'm trying on the native boxplot function, using ~ shall combine different variables on the X axis.

My book gives two examples

```
boxplot(len ~ supp, data = ToothGrowth)
```

and

```
boxplot(len ~ supp + dose, data = ToothGrowth)
```

I do understand the first one, but what does `+` in `boxplot(len ~ supp + dose, data = ToothGrowth)` do? The output is confusing for me (shown below). [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second instance `len ~ sup + dose` is the equivalent of doing:

```
TG_split <- with(
  ToothGrowth,
  split(len, list(supp, dose)
  )
)

boxplot(TG_split)
```

i.e. it splits the `len` vector by the two factors `supp` and `dose`, and gives you the values of `len` for every combination of the two factors.

```
TG_split 

$OJ.0.5
 [1] 15.2 21.5 17.6  9.7 14.5 10.0  8.2  9.4 16.5  9.7

 $VC.0.5
  [1]  4.2 11.5  7.3  5.8  6.4 10.0 11.2 11.2  5.2  7.0

 $OJ.1
  [1] 19.7 23.3 23.6 26.4 20.0 25.2 25.8 21.2 14.5 27.3

 $VC.1
  [1] 16.5 16.5 15.2 17.3 22.5 17.3 13.6 14.5 18.8 15.5

 $OJ.2
  [1] 25.5 26.4 22.4 24.5 24.8 30.9 26.4 27.3 29.4 23.0

 $VC.2
  [1] 23.6 18.5 33.9 25.5 26.4 32.5 26.7 21.5 23.3 29.5
```